# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object

Tags: discord.js

Code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix2}red`)){
    if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'streamer')) return message.channel.send("You already has that role")
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'streamer');
    let member = message.member; 
    message.delete(1)
    member.addRole(role).catch(console.error)
        }
    })
```

Error Is:

```
if (typeof options !== 'object') throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE','options', 'object', true);
                                         ^
    TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object
```

not sure what I did to make this happen

Comment: I can’t see where you have typed the if statement `if (typeof options !== 'object')` - is there any chance you could ident your code with backticks aswell please? They help us to see the code properly - read the formatting help for info

Comment: i never used `if (typeof options !== 'object')`

Comment: Have you used a ‘new’ statement anywhere - ie, let <variable> = new <variable>? The ‘new’ will have caused a problem as the variable is not an object

Answer (score 3):

Discord.JS doesn't accept a number anymore in `message.delete()` according to the documentation, `message#delete` only accepts an object. For your case it would be: `message.delete({ timeout: 1 })` but for that amount of time, you don't need to provide anything at all, unless you meant 1 second which would instead be `message.delete({ timeout: 1000 })`.